# Use identifier for index of objects in $[] using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assume I have this document:

```
docs: [
  {
    a: "a"
    b: "b"
  },
  {
    a: "a"
    b: "b"
  },
  {
    a: "a"
    b: "b"
  }
]
```

I need to get this collection as a result:

```
docs: [
  {
    a: "a"
    b: "b"
  },
  {
    a: "a"
    b: "c"
  },
  {
    a: "a"
    b: "c"
  }
]
```

How can I define using $[] and arrayFilters that skip first document and change other documents?

```
db.collection("aaa").update(
  {<query>},
  {$set: {"docs.$[v].b": "c"}},
  {arrayFilters: [{"v": {$not: 0}, "v.a": "a"}],
})
```

Comment: what is your mongodb version ? Also `docs` is an array field in a document right ?

Comment: My Mongodb version is 4.2. Yes, docs is a property of a parent document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MongoDB version >= `4.2` accepts aggregation pipeline in [.update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) operations. You can do this using below query :

**Query :**

```
db.getCollection("collectionName").update(
 {<your filter part plus> , docs: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }}, // checks for `docs` not to be empty or not exists.
 [
  {
    $set: {
      docs: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$docs", 0] }],
          {
            $map: {
              input: { $slice: ["$docs", 1, { $size: "$docs" }] },
              in: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.a", "a" ] }, { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { b: "c" }] } , "$$this" ] } // Conditional check to return same object or updated object.
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** Validate aggregation pipeline here : [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZSpMp0tEWmw)

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

**Explanation :** `$set` is an alias to `$addFields` of aggregation, which will re-create the field if it exists or will create a new field with specified name. At the end `docs` field will be re- created with new array. We're passing an array as `input` to `$map` operator, This input array will be mostly entire original `docs` array but without first element. So `$map` will re-create a new array which will be concatenated with `array converted first element`(for `$concatArrays` both args should be array, So we're pulling first object of `$docs` array and wrapping with `[]` to make it an array) of `docs` array. `$mergeObjects` will replace just the `b` field inside each object of `docs` array with `{ b: "c" }` but rest all other fields in object will remain same.

Comment: Thank you Whoami, but this in not what I need exactly. Because you did not consider "v.a": "a".  Therefor if I have two more documents at the beginning of docs, like:
      {
        "a": "a",
        "b": "b"
      },
      {
        "a": "d",
        "b": "b"
      }
Then it will change second doc too, while I need to stay the second unchanged.

Comment: @weera : Do you mean this update has to happen only for the objects where `a: "a"` ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely!